# Unity Transform.Position объекта в определенных пределах

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ребят, подскажите, как код исправить. Выдает всего `Bad`. Нужно, чтобы выдавало `Good`. Объект является дочерним, но пробовал с `localPosition`, и результат не изменился!

```
if (nailMain.transform.position.x > 3.737f && nailMain.transform.position.x < 4.154f)
    print("Good");
else 
    print("Bad");
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы выдавало `Good`:

```
if (nailMain.transform.position.x > 3.737f && nailMain.transform.position.x < 4.154f)
    print("Good");
else 
    print("Good");
```

или просто

```
print("Good");
```

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не самый лучший программист, но чисто по интуиции мне что-то подсказывает, что позиция вашего объекта по x не больше 3.737 и не меньше 4.154.

Честно, не знаю, почему я так решил, но, возможно, проблема именно в этом.

А если серьезно ваш код рабочий, выведите в консоль реальную позицию и посмотрите и сравните.

Comment: да, я исправил уже. Добавил посмотрел, там дело в префабе было. Он не отцентрован был

Comment: Я не претендую на то, что бы вы приняли мой ответ, потому что давая его, чисто рофлил. Но ваш вопрос, согласитесь, не является каким-то важным. Поэтому советую вам либо удалить его, так как вряд ли он является очень полезным, либо самому дать ответ и принять его